# How to pass the cell index into the previewProvider of a context menu in swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I have the following and I am trying to understand how to pass the `indexPath.row` for the `UICollectionViewCell` into the `previewProvider` so that I can preview a larger version of the selected image.

I have an array of larger images that are referenced via the `indexPath.row`

I have tried changing to makeRatePreview(cellIndex: Int) and passing in the index but this only throws errors.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                                 contextMenuConfigurationForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath,
                                 point: CGPoint) -> UIContextMenuConfiguration? {
        
        return UIContextMenuConfiguration(identifier: nil, previewProvider: makeRatePreview) { suggestedActions in
            
            let inspectAction =
                UIAction(title: NSLocalizedString("InspectTitle", comment: ""),
                         image: UIImage(systemName: "arrow.up.square")) { action in
                }
            
            let deleteAction =
                UIAction(title: NSLocalizedString("DeleteTitle", comment: ""),
                         image: UIImage(systemName: "trash"),
                         attributes: .destructive) { action in
                }
            
            return UIMenu(title: "", children: [inspectAction, deleteAction])
        }
    }
    
    
    // MARK: - Context menu for images
    
    func makeRatePreview() -> UIViewController {
        
      let viewController = UIViewController()
      
      // 1
      let imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "rating_star"))
      viewController.view = imageView
      
      // 2
      imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100)
      imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        imageView.backgroundColor = .blue
      
      // 3
      viewController.preferredContentSize = imageView.frame.size
      
      return viewController
    }
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused what you want to do with `cellIndex` if you did pass it in, can you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: Sure, I have a uicollectionview that has a number of small square thumbnails. When the user clicks on cell I would like to replace the rating_star image with a large version of thumb with a correct ratio. I am just wondering if it is possible to pass data into the preview provider

Comment: What errors did you get when you tried to do that (by string interpolation I assume, e.g. `"rating_star_\(cellIndex)"`)?

Comment: So far I have tried changing the function to `func makeRatePreview(cellIndex:Int) -> UIViewController` and then calling it with `makeRatePreview(cellIndex: 0)`.  I end up with the following error `Cannot convert value of type 'UIViewController' to expected argument type 'UIContextMenuContentPreviewProvider?' (aka 'Optional<() -> Optional<UIViewController>>')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UIContextMenuConfiguration`'s initializer expects `UIContextMenuContentPreviewProvider` for the `previewProvider` argument.

In the documentation:

```
public typealias UIContextMenuContentPreviewProvider = () -> UIViewController?
```

This means we want to pass in a closure. You could pass in `makeRatePreview` fine since it is of type `() -> UIViewController`.

However, when you changed it to `makeRatePreview(cellIndex: 0)` it is now of type `UIViewController`, which is incorrect. To fix this, just put it in a closure by adding `{ ... }` around the call:

```
{ makeRatePreview(cellIndex: 0) }
```

Comment: Thanks, for explaining it and it now accepts the values. I need to go and review how the closures work again.